Movie where kids are sold to a dentist or eye doctor
I remember watching this movie as a kid and can only remember the general plot and two scenes. Hoping someone knows what it is it.
The general plot: the parents leave their kids (boy younger, maybe like 10, the girl early teen...maybe) with a "babysitter" for a period of time. This woman is a criminal (shoplifting I think). The kids are spoiled brats and she ends up selling them to a dentist or eye doctor.
Scene: Kids are at the table pounding their fork and knife on the table chanting something like "We Want Food!", pretty much being horrible, spoiled children. 
Scene: Kids are with the dentists/eye doctor. The boy is in the doctor's chair with something on his eyes to keep him from blinking (so maybe he's an eye doctor). The babysitter ends up coming in and saving them after she sold them to him. 
Movie must have come out in 90s and in the US. Saw it on TV so it might just be a TV film.

This is The Crazysitter from 1994 starring Beverly D'Angelo.

When a petty criminal escapes from jail, she lays low by posing as a babysitter for two seemingly precious children. But when she decides to sell them for a quick profit, she gets more than she bargained for. A wildy clever family comedy in the tradition of "Home Alone" and "Mrs. Doubtfire".

Both of the scenes that you mentioned are there. The first one appears in the film's first few minutes and you can see the kids at the doctor's here. It also stars Ed Begley Jr., Carol Kane, Phil Hartman and Lisa Kudrow. Here's the trailer:



